# Maariv After Bedtime Shema

Tags: halacha, shema, maariv, hamapil

Many a time I realize that I have forgotten to say Maariv in midst of reciting the bedtime Shema.

Halachic Question: Is one permitted to Daven Maariv after saying ברוך המפיל?

Comment: if you haven't finished krias shema al hamita you could always stop. daven maariv and then say hamapil afterwards

Comment: Can you say morning blessings after Shacharit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you need to pray maariv. Even if we say that the Kriat Shema of bedtime made you quite for the mitsvat KS and Yetsiat Mitsrayim (If you said also Vayomer). If you read in [S.A. O.C. 239](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1063) and mefarshim, you will see that to say some psalms for shmira after blessing hamapil because of the importance of Shmira. A fortiori, a mitsva as Arvit. 2 brachot before Shema, 2 after it. Even to go at Shtiblech to pray be minyan is allowed. In the Tur & Bet Yosef at the [same siman](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x947) there is no mention of "prohibition to speak", but Bet Yosef mentioned in name of Kol Bo, Rabenu Yerucham and Rokeach, not to eat, drink or speak after KS al Hamita. No mention of Hamapil. No mention of praying or make a mitsva or to go to bathroom.

You need to make a separation between 2 problems, 1.- is the bracha of Hamapil canceled if after it you make something, is it Bracha Levatala and you need to say Baruch Shem Kevod Malchuto... , need you to blessing it next time at the new bedtime. 2.- Is there a cancellation of all obligation through this Bracha.

The second point is obviously not right, because for such a Chiddush we need a proof and nobody in SA treat this. The Magen Avraham told about a man who want to be in marital relationship and advise to say Hamapil after but he doesn't say that marital relationship is prohibited after Hamapil.

The only considerations concerning things after Hamapil are Lechatechilla (is it right to make this a priori). But nothing is written Bedieved (a posteriori).

Arvit is a duty (despite that originally arvit is reshut) and we need to consider it as a duty already at the time you said Hamapil. You cannot cancel a duty.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite an interesting question! One would surely say maariv, even if he said birkat hamapil. Ideally, one would fall asleep for a small amount of time, wake up, and say maariv, but if this isn’t possible then just say maariv.

Comment: _The Rabbis decreed: one should not come in the evening and say let me eat a bit and sleep a bit and then pray, for he will sleep through the night. And all who violate the words of the Rabbis deserve death. --Berakhot 4b_

Comment: Please remember to source your answer. Otherwise it is just an anonymous view and we don't know your qualifications. Nothing personal, that is just how the site works