# Speaking divrei torah after hamapil

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, bircas-krias-shema, hamapil

Is it allowed to repeat psukim or to pray (uttering the words with your mouth) After you have finished your kiriat shma al hamita and said birkat hamapil? Would  be Happy to See sources.

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן עא - סדר הלילה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0070_L2) says:

> וּלְאַחַר שֶׁאָמַר בִּרְכַּת הַמַּפִּיל, לֹא יֹאכַל וְלֹא יִשְׁתֶּה וְלֹא יְדַבֵּר עַד שֶׁיִּישַׁן. אִם אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִישֹׁן יֹאמַר עוֹד הַפַּעַם קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע וְהַמִּזְמוֹרִים וּפְסוּקֵי דְּרַחְמֵי, וְחוֹזֵר וְקוֹרֵא עַד שֶׁתַּחְטְפֶנּוּ שֵׁנָה, אוֹ יֹאמַר כַּמָּה פְּעָמִים פְּסוּקִים אֵלּוּ, תּוֹרָה צִוָּה לָנוּ וְגוֹ' אֵשׁ תָּמִיד וְגוֹ' סֵעֲפִים שָׂנֵאתָ וְגוֹ', אוֹר זָרוּעַ וְגוֹ' עַד שֶׁתַּחְטְפֶנּוּ שֵׁנָה‏

After Hamapil one should not eat nor drink. If one cannot fall asleep then one can say the Shma again or other verses in the Krias Shma Al HaMitah that one just finished reciting - or other Psukim that he mentions.

Presumably, this is what the Remo means in Shulchan Aruch [סימן רלט](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_23.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2)  when he says:

> וְאִם קָרָא קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע וְלֹא יוּכַל לִישַׁן מִיָּד, אָז  חוֹזֵר וְקוֹרֵא כַּמָּה פְּעָמִים זֶה אַחַר זֶה עַד שֶׁיִּשְׁתַּקַּע בְּשֵׁנָה וְשֶׁיִּהְיֶה קְרִיאָתוֹ סָמוּךְ לִשְׁנָתוֹ (הַגָּהוֹת מַיְמוֹנִי פ''ז)‏

Though possibly he means that one simply repeats the Shma.

The [קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_22.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) says that one may make Brachot like Asher Yotzar (if one had to relieve oneself) or Shehakol on Borei Nefashot (if one desperately had to eat/drink) - and one may even talk if absolutely necessary - like soothing a child.

> יש להשתדל בכל עוז **שלא להפסיק בדיבור בין הברכה לשינה**, זולת בפסוקי קריאת שמע ושאר פסוקים שבסידורים (הנאמרים לאחר ברכת המפיל). ואם עבר ודיבר, אין ברכתו לבטלה, ואינו צריך לחזור ולברך כלל. ואם תאב לשתות אחר שבירך המפיל. **רשאי לברך ברכת הנהנין בלא כל חשש**, וכן **יש להקל לדבר דיבור נחוץ**. כגון להשתיק ילד, או לברך ברכת אשר יצר, אם הוצרך לנקביו, לאחר שבירך המפיל. ומנהגינו לברך ''המפיל'' קודם קריאת שמע. ‏

Comment: Btw the Kitzur here is mistaken. לֹא יֹאכַל וְלֹא יִשְׁתֶּה וְלֹא יְדַבֵּר עַד שֶׁיִּישַׁן was said about Shema not HaMapil.

Answer (score 2):

See RMA in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 239,  1:

> ואם קרא קריאת שמע ולא יוכל לישן מיד אז חוזר וקורא כמה פעמים זה אחר זה עד שישתקע בשינה ושיהיה קריאתו סמוך לשינתו (הגהות מיימוני פרק ז').‏
>
> If he already did read Shema (and Hamapil according to the context of this note),  he can read it  again several times up to falling asleep...

From the Magen Avraham and the Mishna Berura it seems that there are two opinions in Talmud Yerushalmi that lead to two different customs in Rishonim. For the Shulchan Aruch and the Tur Shema is before Hamapil,  for the Rambam Hamapil is before Shema.

1. The minhag of the Rambam is to say hamapil before Kriat Shema,  the Magen Avraham understands that it is allowed to read Tora after Hamapil.
2. The Shulchan Aruch followed an other opinion in Yerushalmi.   First Kriat Shema and afterwards Hamapil. The reason is,  according to the Magen Avraham,  that one cannot say anything after Hamapil. But one exception is the permission to say mizmorim for protection as Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi (Yerushalmi) made.

Magen Avraham,  explained that the difference between the two opinions is how to understand  the function of Shema before sleeping:  If Shema before sleeping is said  for protection or as Tora words.

.  If Shema is comparable to simple Tora words,  we have to say it before Hamapil.

.  If it is for  protection, we need to say it after Hamapil, near to falling asleep.

**From the Magen Avraham we learn  that we need to say Hamapil after all learning words.**

The RMA above cited  seems to understand the  issue differently than Magen Avraham,  because he advised to repeat Shema after  Hamapil when it is hard to fall asleep.  And he said this according to the Shulchan Aruch for which Shema is a kind of divre Tora only (according to the Magen Avraham).

There are also opinions following which  Hamapil may be understood as  a blessing regarding the general behavior,  not specifically the man who is blessing. (Chaye Adam  reported in Beur Halacha).

**In conclusion it's better to learn by thinking without pronunciation of words if you already said Hamapil, or repeat Shema according to the RMA.**

See [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76034/9215)  about the fact that there's **no real prohibition to speak after Hamapil.**