# Is one allowed to make Berachos after saying the bedtime Shema?

Tags: halacha, blessing, hamapil

As recorded in the sources cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60384/9682), most Poskim say that one may not speak after saying the bedtime Shema, and some say even after saying Hamapil.

Let’s say that one hears thunder after saying Hamapil and Shema. Can he make a Shekocho U’gevuraso on it? If he sees lightning, can he make an Oseh Ma’aseh Bereishis? Would this be the same Halacha as [saying Maariv afterwards](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76032/9682)?

Comment: Just say Shema again if you're worried about it being the last thing you say. Why might this be different from Maariv? Is it less obligatory? Please edit to clarify

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/903567/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/kaylie-counselor-shiur-hamapil/

Comment: Rav Shlomo Zalmen Aurbach ZTL, quoted in Halichos Shlomo 13:24, Shailos Utshuvos Yisa Yosef  vol. 4 #55 quoting Rav YS Elyashiv ZTL, and Shailos Utshuvos Rivivos Ephraim vol.1 #180 All say that one should say the bracha on thunder and lightening when heard after bedtime krias Shema.

Comment: @ribbis are those Poskim speaking according to the [recently invented] opinion that speaking after HaMappil is forbidden, or like the majority traditional opinion that it's fine? If the latter then you have no proof